# How to make a widescreen background for vertical video with JS/CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, video, html5-video

I have different videos on my website. 
Videos play in horizontal frame, but some of them are vertical.

I want to make vertical videos more beautiful like on the pictures bellow. I want to do it without converting video
[example of processed video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sIwX.jpg)

[image]

**What I've tried**:

I can achieve the same effct by using this FFmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex '[0:v]scale=ih*16/9:-1,boxblur=luma_radius=min(h\,w)/20:luma_power=1:chroma_radius=min(cw\,ch)/20:chroma_power=1[bg];[bg][0:v]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2,crop=h=iw*9/16' outputfile.mp4
```

But I want to change video display background with only Javascript and CSS if it's possible.

Comment: Could you expand a bit more on what you want to achieve? How is the amount of blur determined and what part of the video is to be used for that blur?

Comment: @DmitriyKulesh You must first create a Canvas that is the same size as "background" then draw the Video element into it (captures the pixels of video). Then you can effect those pixels (RGB) with your blur function, or just apply CSS Blur on the Canvas element itself. Use CSS `z-index` to layer the Video object above the Canvas object.

Comment: Could you jsut play the video behind the video that is in focus, with a much wider width to make it distorted?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2023/07/recreating-youtube-ambient-mode-glow-effect/. That should give you a basic idea on how to achieve the effect.